# Docker swarm ingress - unable to connect through two networks

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, mesh-network, docker-ingress

I tried to run docker swarm over two different networks.

- **First network** is 10.10.100.x/24
- **Second network** is 10.10.150.x/24

Both networks can see each other. There are no firewall rules between them to block any traffic.
Specifically I tested 7946 TCP and UDP and 4789 UDP. I can confirm, that I can connect from the first network to the second network on both ports and both protocols. And also from the second network to the first network without any issue.

Docker swarm is up and running and used engine is `20.10.11`
I can see that all nodes have **status=Ready** and **availability=Active**.

Ingress network is default:

[image]

and I can see all peers listed there as well.

But when I deploy any service to any node with port `-p 20000:80`, then I can see this node only from the network where it was deployed.

- If service lands on the first network, it is accessible only through nodes from the first network, not from the second.
- If service lands on the second network, it is accessible only through nodes from the second network, not from the first.

[image]

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Thanks

---

update 1:

Tried to run swarm with additional parameter `docker swarm init --default-addr-pool 172.100.0.0/16`. Result remains the same.

---

update 2:
Based on the advice from @BMitch

I verified with `sudo tcpdump -nn -s0 -v port 4789 or 7946`, that port 7946 works (UDP and TCP).
I also verified with the previous `tcpdump` command and `nc -z -v -u 10.10.150.200 4789` (run from the first network), that port 4789 works as well.

Comment: How did you connect to port 4789/udp? Udp is a connectionless protocol.

Comment: Setup tcpdump on each side of the connection, and verify packets for the overlay ports sent from one node are received by the destination node.

Comment: @BMitch to "connect" to UDP I used some command I found earlier. Unfortunately can't remember what was the command. 

I also never worked with tcpdump. How do I set it up for swarm? Should I set listening on my physical network adapter or some docker network (docker_gwbridge)? And then how do I sent those packets? 

Thanks

Comment: You run it on the hosts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60497618/596285

Comment: What ip addresses did you use in the docker swarm init / docker swarm join commands? wrt --advertizse-addr etc?

Comment: @BMitch I tested it with `tcpdump` and it seems that ports are opened (update 2)

Comment: @ChrisBecke The default ones. I just run `docker swarm init`, it generates join command and I use this command on worker nodes. It creates whole swarm for me.

I also tried it with `--default-addr-pool 172.100.0.0/16`, but the behavior remained the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end - problem was in the NAT. Our second network was behind NAT, which caused this issue. Once we removed NAT, everything worked.

Comment: I have the same issue, could you please advise how did you removed the NAT? is it from iptables?

Comment: @Igbaryya Sorry, I do not know how (it was done by my team mate). You can try to ask a new question here on the StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me, routing and overlay work great but ingress load balancer only works through the same site endpoints that runs the container.

Oddly I discovered ingress load balancer works cross sites when using `nc -l` as server socket, making the whole even more obscure to me.

REM: Underlay network is wireguard VPN (L3 point-to-point)

Comment: We were able to resolve it by removing NAT
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73415943/2972326