# Docker swarm service mesh does not extend over AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm

We had a docker swarm cluster in our on-prem datacenter and a side-by-side vpn to our vpc in aws cloud. Now we want to extend the swarm over the vpn to aws. We had spawned 3 EC2 instances, installed the docker on them and joined them into the swarm cluster. The nodes had joined the cluster successfully and the services are getting deployed on them. But the swarm overlay network does not seem to work correctly. The services can query each other through it only if they are located on the nodes in the same location: i.e. if the services are both located on datacenter or aws node. If one of the services is in datacenter and other in aws, they can not connect. Also published services are available only on the nodes, which are located in the same location, the service is running.

We had opened all traffic for ip address range on the security group, attached to the EC2 instances, but still are getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if anyone finds this question, the issue was the NAT between the AWS cloud and the datacenter, just like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158998/docker-swarm-ingress-unable-to-connect-through-two-networks) question.